# Is a function with nested functions considered a single function?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm new to JavaScript and working on a coding challenge as part of a bootcamp application process.

The question requires writing a single function to accomplish a task.

Although I've looked far and wide, I've yet to come across an answer.

If I write a function that contains other, nested functions, would that still be considered one function?

Comment: It depends on the person assessing you, but to be safe, I'd definitely avoid doing that. Instead, you can always use `this` if need be.

Comment: A function with nested functions sort of becomes a "class" or "module" at that point. Functionally (heh!), it's more than a single function, but syntactically it's just one. It's open to interpretation for sure, but to play it safe I would probably avoid the nesting.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I've just started learning about object oriented programming. I don't exactly know how to use this

Comment: Nearly any code that you write is going to call some kind of function or another so you are arguing semantics if there is a complaint about using a nested function that you wrote. For example, let's say you use`Math.min` inside your function, then its stilled considered a single function. What would you writing your own `min` function inside your function change that logic?

Comment: @ObsidianAge—how are multiple functions replaced by *this*, the value of which can be any object (or any value in strict mode) and may be different on every call of the function?

Comment: @RobG -- The context is vague. I wasn't suggesting that multiple functions can be replaced by `this`, but rather that you can use `this` from within a function to refer to the object the function belongs to. You could also use `.call()` or `.apply()` to change the context of `this`, and probably eliminate the need for nested functions entirely. Considering it's for an assessment that specifically asks for 'one function', I wouldn't even risk `.call()` or `.apply()`, as you can't rest know how the assessor will be lenient. Conditional `return`s would probably suffice for the task at hand :)

Answer (score 3):

> If I write a function that contains other, nested functions, would that still be considered one function?

Yes. A function is an encapsulation unit, it's a blackbox. You can call it, and get results back, but how it is implemented does not matter when looking from outside. A function that modularises its internal implementation into multiple local function is indistinguishable from one that does not as long as it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From a technical perspective you can't even write a function that doesn't call use nested functions. The act of declaring variables alone is going to call a chain of functions to allocate memory which in turn eventually calls functions in assembly which then calls functions in your processor to which calls functions to your memory driver which calls.

Similarly calling operators to set or manipulate your variables are function calls which are all layered APIS calling a chain of functions.

Suppose you write a function `min` that looks like this:

```
function min(a,b) {
    return Math.min(a,b);
}
```

This is still a single function even though it is calling a global function.

The same logic applies if you write an internal function for a complex object

```
function min(data) {
    var smallest = function(a,b) { 
        if (a.x<b.x) { return a;}
        else if (a.y>b.y) { return b;}
        else if (a.y<b.y) return a;
        return b;
    }
    return smallest(data[0],data[b]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's useful to characterise internal workings as function calls, the  OP is clearly about native functions.

Comment: Thank you! This is a helpful explanation